# How can I send a fax to local fax machine from browser with number

Tags: javascript, fax

I am investigating ways of sending faxes from my web application written in CF10.

I know that there are many email-to-fax services available, but I am trying to avoid using one of these services, for both financial reasons and HIPAA compliance reasons.  Yes, I know that some of these services offer HIPAA services, but I have not found a service yet that would be able to transmit a PDF that has been encrypted and password protected.

What I am looking to do is to send a command from the browser to the default printer, which would be a fax machine (actually, an all-in-one with fax).

I know that javascript has the window.print() command, which I imagine would probably work for my purposes.

The only problem is that I need to be able to send the fax number from the browser so that the user doesn't have to manually enter it in each time they want to send a fax.

This is for a specific client set up on a specific computer, so any fax services or third-party solutions that would need to be set up on the client's computer would be acceptable.

Any ideas?

Comment: So your application that is run on your web server will generate an HTML form that via a user's browser can tell a fax machine connected to the user's computer to send the contents of said form? How would CF even figure into this? No commands would go from the browser to CF before going to the fax.

Comment: I fail to see why this is tagged as 'ColdFusion'. If everything happens from the user's browser, ColdFusion will have nothing to do with the process.

Comment: I removed the CF tag.

Comment: Kind of an interesting idea.  I saw this link at it got me thinking.  http://superuser.com/questions/411219/how-to-automate-sending-faxes-on-windows-7

Could you stuff a zipfile with your PDF and a "config" file with the phone number.  Then have your user save the file to a queue folder.  You would need to write a local application that monitor the queue, unzip, read the config and send through windows fax - probably a build in fax modem, and then delete when done.  Your client would probably need an app written as a windows service.

Comment: How many computers nowadays have built-in fax modems, much less a RJ45 port?  Would the script you mentioned be run on the client side or the server side?  Can VB Script be run on any other browser besides IE, not to mention whether it is even supported anymore on other browsers?

Comment: @RickInWestPalmBeach I hear you, but you can always go to tiger direct and pick up a card and slap it in, or maybe something usb.  I was thinking the file scripting itself is browser independant and runs as as executable when the PC loads and monitors a particular folder on the pc like C:\incoming.  If your not familiar with non-web programming, you could probably outsource it reasonably priced.  The issue you'll face with all-in-ones is that their fax driver always pops up a dialing box when you send to them, so you probably cant avoid manual phone number entry with that avenue.

Comment: The computers that will be used with this application are all-in-one touch screen units, so adding a card would not work.  The USB idea may work though.  Still have to find a way to get the fax number from he browser to the fax modem.  I may write a Windows Service, perhaps with FAXCOMEX as others have suggested, that monitors a directory as you suggested with the filename as the fax number.  Thanks for the help.